# ios explore other application folder with jailbreak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, jailbreak

I have an ipad jailbroken.
I need to write a program that can opens other file from other application.

ApplicationA is my app and I need to open a specific file in a folder called ApplicationB that is in var/mobile/applications

Is it possible on jailbroken device?
I'ms sure that is not possible in non-jailbrekon device for the sandbox.

Comment: It is possible (you can do anything you want with a jailbroken device), but the specified API isn't setup to do that so you will probably have to muck around with stuff that most people have no idea how to use.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's possible. You'll have to iterate through every folder in /var/mobile/applications/ to find the correct folder for the app that you're looking for. Then you can do whatever you want with that knowledge.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes but my problem is how can I access to that path? can you show me an example? I can't use official api right?

Comment: thanks but how can I access to a specific folder of an app? if the name is sandboxed how can I look for what I want? thanks

Comment: Each app folder has an `iTunesMetadata.plist`. Check that to see what app the folder is for.